How can I replace single angle brackets with doubles with Notepad++?
I have hundreds of text files under a directory that contain (correctly) some tokens surrounded with << >> like:
Hello, my name is <<myName>> and I am the manager of the <<teamName>> team.

But in some files, some of the tokens are "incorrectly" between < > like:
Hi, this is <myName> from the <<teamName>> team.

How can I use the "Find in Files" feature in Notepad++ to find such < > tokens and replace them with the correct << >> ones?

Have you asked an AI before asking here? it's pretty basic

You can use replace with regex, your regex can be:
(?<!<)<([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)>(?!>)

and replace with can be:
<<\1>>

Like this:

